# How to merge two xml files using XSLT1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to merge two xml files using XSLT1.0. I am trying to merge FileOne and Filetwo to merge to a new xml file. The resultant xml should contain one element from file two based on the value from measurement tag. Any help would be greatly appreciated

## Fileone.xml

```
<Schedule name="NE3S">
    <Item scheduleId="1" startDate="2013-01-01" stopDate="2037-12-31">
        <measurements>
            <measurement>PGW0001</measurement>
        </measurements>
        <measPeriods>
            <period day="0" duration="0" hour="0" interval="15" minutes="0"/>
        </measPeriods>
    </Item>
    <Item scheduleId="2" startDate="2013-01-01" stopDate="2037-12-31">
        <measurements>
            <measurement>PGW0002</measurement>
        </measurements>
        <measPeriods>
            <period day="0" duration="0" hour="0" interval="60" minutes="0"/>
        </measPeriods>
    </Item>
</Schedule>
```

## Filetwo.xml

```
<Schedule name="NE3S">
    <Item scheduleId="1" startDate="2013-01-01" stopDate="2037-12-31">
        <measurements>
        <measurement>PGW0001</measurement>
    </measurements>
    <measPeriods>
        <period day="0" duration="0" hour="0" interval="60" minutes="0"/>
    </measPeriods>
    </Item>
    <Item scheduleId="2" startDate="2013-01-01" stopDate="2037-12-31">
        <measurements>
            <measurement>PGD0001</measurement>
        </measurements>
    <measPeriods>
        <period day="0" duration="0" hour="0" interval="60" minutes="0"/>
    </measPeriods>
    </Item>
    <Item scheduleId="3" startDate="2013-01-01" stopDate="2037-12-31">
        <measurements>
            <measurement>PGW0002</measurement>
        </measurements>
        <measPeriods>
            <period day="0" duration="0" hour="0" interval="60" minutes="0"/>
        </measPeriods>
    </Item>
</Schedule>
```

My expected output is

```
<Schedule name="NE3S">
    <Item scheduleId="1" startDate="2013-01-01" stopDate="2037-12-31">
        <measurements>
            <measurement>PGW0001</measurement>
        </measurements>
        <measPeriods>
            <period day="0" duration="0" hour="0" interval="15" minutes="0"/>
        </measPeriods>
    </Item>
    <Item scheduleId="2" startDate="2013-01-01" stopDate="2037-12-31">
        <measurements>
            <measurement>PGD0001</measurement>
        </measurements>
        <measPeriods>
            <period day="0" duration="0" hour="0" interval="60" minutes="0"/>
        </measPeriods>
    </Item>
    <Item scheduleId="3" startDate="2013-01-01" stopDate="2037-12-31">
        <measurements>
            <measurement>PGW0002</measurement>
        </measurements>
        <measPeriods>
            <period day="0" duration="0" hour="0" interval="60" minutes="0"/>
        </measPeriods>
    </Item>
</Schedule>
```

please note that expected output

```
<measPeriods>
  <period day="0" duration="0" hour="0" interval="15" minutes="0"/>
</measPeriods>
```

I tried the following code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="fileName" select="'/opt/Filetwo.xml'" />
<xsl:param name="updates" select="document($fileName)" />

<xsl:variable name="updateMeasurement" select="$updates/Schedule/Item" />

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Schedule">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Item[not(measurements/measurement = $updateMeasurement/measurements/measurement)]" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/Schedule/Item//measurements" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$updates/Schedule/Item/measPeriods" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>


xsltproc merge.xslt /opt/Fileone.xml > /opt/FileThree.xml
```

my expected output should have the `<measPeriods>` tag from `Fileone.xml` if the value in `<measurements>/<measurement>` matches

edited my solution to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"
encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="addresses"
select="document('/opt/esymac/extras/esymacstarter/schedule/MJ.netact.xml_backup')"/>
   <xsl:template match="/measSchedule">
        <measSchedule name="NE3S">
        <xsl:for-each select="scheduleItem">
           <xsl:variable name="id" select="@scheduleId"/>
           <xsl:variable name="startDate" select="@startDate"/>
           <xsl:variable name="stopDate" select="@stopDate"/>
           <xsl:variable name="day" select="measPeriods/period/@day"/>
           <xsl:variable name="duration" select="measPeriods/period/@duration"/>
           <xsl:variable name="hour" select="measPeriods/period/@hour"/>
           <xsl:variable name="minutes" select="measPeriods/period/@minutes"/>

           <xsl:variable name="interval"
select="$addresses/measSchedule/scheduleItem/measurements[$counterId =
@measurement]/measPeriods/@interval"/>
             <Item scheduleId="{$id}" startDate="{$startDate}" stopDate="{$stopDate}">
             <measurements>
                <measurement><xsl:value-of select="measurements/measurement"/></measurement>
             </measurements>
             <measPeriods>
                   <period day="{$day}" duration="{$duration}" hour="{$hour}" interval="{$interval}" minutes="{$minutes}"/>
             </measPeriods>
             </Item>
    </xsl:for-each>
</measSchedule>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

now i am getting Item tag properly but

```
<period day="{$day}" duration="{$duration}" hour="{$hour}" interval="{$interval}" minutes="{$minutes}"/>
```

is still not proper

Comment: Your stylesheet reflects a logic opposite to your expected output and problem definition. Also, the merge key is not only `measurements`.

Comment: How do i merge based on multiple keys?

Comment: Initially i had kept  <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="scheduleItem[not(measurements/measurement = $updateMeasurement/measurements/measurement)]" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$updateMeasurement" />
    </xsl:copy> but it resulted in a different output.. Was trying to experiment with different logic

Comment: edited my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the input XMLs, it looks like `Fileone.xml` has a subset of records from the `Filetwo.xml`. An easier approach will be write the XSL and apply it on `Filetwo.xml` (since it has all the records and we have to replace only few) and access `Fileone.xml` using the `document()` function.

For the matching value of `<measurement>`, you can use the `<xsl:choose></xsl:choose>` to copy `period` from `Fileone.xml` and for the non-matching value, retain `period` from `Filetwo.xml`. Below is the `<xsl:choose>` block.

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$extSchedule/Item/measurements/measurement = current()/ancestor::Item/measurements/measurement">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$extSchedule/Item[measurements/measurement = current()/ancestor::Item/measurements/measurement]/measPeriods/period" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="period" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Here `current()` is used to access the correct node and its corresponding sibling's `measurement` value.

The complete XSLT is as below

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:param name="fileName" select="document('Fileone.xml')" />
    <xsl:variable name="extSchedule" select="$fileName/Schedule" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="measPeriods">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$extSchedule/Item/measurements/measurement = current()/ancestor::Item/measurements/measurement">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$extSchedule/Item[measurements/measurement = current()/ancestor::Item/measurements/measurement]/measPeriods/period" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="period" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output below shows the `period` for `PGW0001` has been replaced with the corresponding node from `Fileone.xml`.

```
<Schedule name="NE3S">
    <Item scheduleId="1" startDate="2013-01-01" stopDate="2037-12-31">
        <measurements>
            <measurement>PGW0001</measurement>
        </measurements>
        <measPeriods>
            <period day="0" duration="0" hour="0" interval="15" minutes="0" />
        </measPeriods>
    </Item>
    <Item scheduleId="2" startDate="2013-01-01" stopDate="2037-12-31">
        <measurements>
            <measurement>PGD0001</measurement>
        </measurements>
        <measPeriods>
            <period day="0" duration="0" hour="0" interval="60" minutes="0" />
        </measPeriods>
    </Item>
    <Item scheduleId="3" startDate="2013-01-01" stopDate="2037-12-31">
        <measurements>
            <measurement>PGW0002</measurement>
        </measurements>
        <measPeriods>
            <period day="0" duration="0" hour="0" interval="60" minutes="0" />
        </measPeriods>
    </Item>
</Schedule>
```

Comment: Thanks Aniket.. This solution worked wonderfully. One small doubt further, when i execute this in linux through xsltproc command, the whole output seems to be in a single line.. is there anyway to avoid it?

Comment: <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" /> this indented the output.. Thanks for your efforts aniket.. Much appreciated. I am a seasoned java developer trying my hands on XSLT for the first time and was finding difficult to learn this non functional language..

Comment: If the answer has worked for you, could you please accept the answer. [How to accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)